# phpmyadmin 3.4.0 ERD to PDF

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, export, entity-relationship, export-to-pdf

I can create an ERD in phpmyadmin 3.4.0 with the Designer tool, but how do I export it as a PDF?

I can see the [Import/Export coordinates for PDF schema] button, but cannot see what it does, or how to get a PDF of my ERD.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: detail step to generate ERD : http://goo.gl/0z3vFE

Answer (score 6):

You've done the first step right. From the Designer, click the Import/Export coordinates for PDF schema button and provide a name. Next, go to the Operations tab. Near the bottom click the link "Edit or export relational schema". From that page, select the name of the page you created in Designer. The page will load with a bunch of information and a list of all the tables.

You can "Toggle scratchboard" to adjust the layout, or scroll down to de-select some columns from display. Keep scrolling down :-). If you've made changes to the layout, you can click "Save" to, well, save those changes, or just keep going down, where you can select a page size and other options. Finally, press the "Go" button. You'll get a PDF file which, by default, has quite a bit of information including, on the last page, the Designer view export you seek.

Comment: Thanks for this. I created a tutorial with screenshots [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755930/how-to-save-erd-as-pdf-or-image-in-phpmyadmin-with-screenshots).

Answer (score -1):

Just click on your diagram->On your main tab menu choose Export->Choose the export method (e.g. Quick)->From the drop down choose PDF->Go->Save to location you prefer.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your point, that's for creating a PDF export of your data, not the Designer schema.