# How to export/save ERD as PDF or as image in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, erd

I have generated an ERD using the Designer in phpMyAdmin.

How do I save it as PDF or image?

> **On possible duplicate:**
>
> The "original" thread is referenced in the answer. This post is intended to be a visual tutorial thread with screenshots which the other thread does not have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [phpmyadmin 3.4.0 ERD to PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560025/phpmyadmin-3-4-0-erd-to-pdf)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### To save as PDF:

1) Select databse.

[image]

2) More > Designer

[image]

3) Import/Export coordinates for relational schema [image]

[image]

[image]

4) Operations (scroll down) > Edit or export relational schema

[image]

[image]

Click Go.

5) Choose your preferences.

[image]

Click Go.

[image]

Save the file.

---

### To save as image:

You can choose "SVG" in Step 5 instead of "PDF", but the it did not produce aesthetically desirable results for the ERD (at least for me).

I personally just converted the PDF to image using a third-party app.

Reference: [phpmyadmin 3.4.0 ERD to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560025/phpmyadmin-3-4-0-erd-to-pdf)