# Phpmyadmin 414 Designer Export Schema

Tags: phpmyadmin

Phpmyadmin 4.5.5.1

Apache/2.4.6

Php 5.6.5

Phpmyadmin is giving me 414 error when i try to export schema as pdf from Designer. Please see attached image for offending page [Popup from Designer Menu - Export Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRuqw.png)

On clicking the Go buttons, resulting url give this error

Request-URI Too Long
The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.

Url generated is 17860 characters long, which is massive. I have searched all over but not been able to find any one else complaining about this. It should be a POST request instead of GET, may be i am missing something. My designer works great, all the supporting tables are there and i am able to perform all the relations, saving pages and such.

I found this post which have details how to create pdf page and export but i don't have these options.

[How to export/save ERD as PDF or as image in phpMyAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755930/how-to-export-save-erd-as-pdf-or-as-image-in-phpmyadmin)

In my version Designer have menu on the side where all the options are listed. [Phpmyadmin Designer Options Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwsxk.png)

Any ideas how to fix this. 
Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Can you try with a more updated version of phpMyAdmin? Release 4.6.1 is current and 4.6.2 is due out in about a week. 4.5.5.1 is not **that** old but is no longer supported and there have been some improvements made since then. You might also wish to try on the demo server at https://demo.phpmyadmin.net to see if you can reproduce the problem there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i had posted this issue on phpmyadmin git and this bug has been handled in the release 4.6.2. Get method has been replaced by Post. Link to git if someone else looking for this.                           https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12234

Comment: I if u hav got the answer, pls answer the question and mark it as accepted. U will also earn some reputation.

Answer (score 0):

As posted by S.Gill as a comment, this seems to have been a bug with an older phpMYAdmin version; it's been fixed so if you're suffering from the issue try upgrading your phpMyAdmin installation. [Link to the bug report](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12234).